# Javascript Regular Expression performance improvement

Tags: javascript, regex

After having solved [Leetcode 392 Is Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/is-subsequence/) using 2 pointer approach, I am try to solve it using regular expressions. While this works fine for smaller inputs, but is extremely slow when trying with larger inputs.

Problem Summary

> Given two strings s and t, return true if s is a subsequence of t, or
> false otherwise.
>
> A subsequence of a string is a new string that is formed from the
> original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters
> without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters.
> (i.e., "ace" is a subsequence of "abcde" while "aec" is not).
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: s = "abc", t = "ahbgdc" Output: true Example 2:
>
> Input: s = "axc", t = "ahbgdc" Output: false
> Constraints:
>
> 0 <= s.length <= 100
> 0 <= t.length <= 10000
> s and t consist only of lowercase English letters.

This is the code:

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @param {string} t
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isSubsequence = function (s, t) {
    if (s.length > t.length) {
        return false;
    }

    let regex_string = "\\w*";
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        regex_string += s[i] + "\\w*";
    }

    const regex = new RegExp(regex_string);
    return regex.test(t);
};


let s = "rjufvjafbxnbgriwgokdgqdqewn";
let t = "mjmqqjrmzkvhxlyruonekhhofpzzslupzojfuoztvzmmqvmlhgqxehojfowtrinbatjujaxekbcydldglkbxsqbbnrkhfdnpfbuaktupfftiljwpgglkjqunvithzlzpgikixqeuimmtbiskemplcvljqgvlzvnqxgedxqnznddkiujwhdefziydtquoudzxstpjjitmiimbjfgfjikkjycwgnpdxpeppsturjwkgnifinccvqzwlbmgpdaodzptyrjjkbqmgdrftfbwgimsmjpknuqtijrsnwvtytqqvookinzmkkkrkgwafohflvuedssukjgipgmypakhlckvizmqvycvbxhlljzejcaijqnfgobuhuiahtmxfzoplmmjfxtggwwxliplntkfuxjcnzcqsaagahbbneugiocexcfpszzomumfqpaiydssmihdoewahoswhlnpctjmkyufsvjlrflfiktndubnymenlmpyrhjxfdcq";

isSubsequence(s, t);
```

How can the performance of the above code be improved while still using regular expressions?

Comment: Please provide a summary of the problem, not just a link to LeetCode.

Comment: Just one upvote after 5 hours? C'mon readers, this is an excellent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w*` causes lots of backtracking, you might be better off setting the "skip" pattern to `[^ next-char]*` explicitly:

```js
var isSubsequence = function (s, t) {
    let regex_string = '';
    for (let c of s) {
        regex_string += '[^' + c + ']*' + c
    }


    const regex = new RegExp(regex_string);
    return regex.test(t);
};

let s = "rjufvjafbxnbgriwgokdgqdqewn";
let t = "mjmqqjrmzkvhxlyruonekhhofpzzslupzojfuoztvzmmqvmlhgqxehojfowtrinbatjujaxekbcydldglkbxsqbbnrkhfdnpfbuaktupfftiljwpgglkjqunvithzlzpgikixqeuimmtbiskemplcvljqgvlzvnqxgedxqnznddkiujwhdefziydtquoudzxstpjjitmiimbjfgfjikkjycwgnpdxpeppsturjwkgnifinccvqzwlbmgpdaodzptyrjjkbqmgdrftfbwgimsmjpknuqtijrsnwvtytqqvookinzmkkkrkgwafohflvuedssukjgipgmypakhlckvizmqvycvbxhlljzejcaijqnfgobuhuiahtmxfzoplmmjfxtggwwxliplntkfuxjcnzcqsaagahbbneugiocexcfpszzomumfqpaiydssmihdoewahoswhlnpctjmkyufsvjlrflfiktndubnymenlmpyrhjxfdcq";

console.time()
console.log(isSubsequence(s, t))
console.timeEnd()
```

If there's a possibility that a string contains special regex chars, these need to be properly escaped.

Comment: The LeetCode problem specifically stipulates that the inputs only contain lowercase letters, so the last issue doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) by forcing matches as early as possible:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @param {string} t
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function isSubsequence(s, t) {
    if (s.length > t.length) {
        return false;
    }

    let regexString = "^";
    for (const c of s) {
        regexString += `[^\\W${c}]*${c}`;
    }
    console.log(regexString);

    const regex = new RegExp(regexString);
    return regex.test(t);
};


let s = "rjufvjafbxnbgriwgokdgqdqewn";
let t = "mjmqqjrmzkvhxlyruonekhhofpzzslupzojfuoztvzmmqvmlhgqxehojfowtrinbatjujaxekbcydldglkbxsqbbnrkhfdnpfbuaktupfftiljwpgglkjqunvithzlzpgikixqeuimmtbiskemplcvljqgvlzvnqxgedxqnznddkiujwhdefziydtquoudzxstpjjitmiimbjfgfjikkjycwgnpdxpeppsturjwkgnifinccvqzwlbmgpdaodzptyrjjkbqmgdrftfbwgimsmjpknuqtijrsnwvtytqqvookinzmkkkrkgwafohflvuedssukjgipgmypakhlckvizmqvycvbxhlljzejcaijqnfgobuhuiahtmxfzoplmmjfxtggwwxliplntkfuxjcnzcqsaagahbbneugiocexcfpszzomumfqpaiydssmihdoewahoswhlnpctjmkyufsvjlrflfiktndubnymenlmpyrhjxfdcq";

isSubsequence(s, t);
```

Comment: Can you help me understand why \W is needed in the negated set?

Comment: It seems you want to allow only `\w` characters between the letters of the subsequence, so I've excluded everything that is not `\w` - `\W`.

Comment: The problem says, "s and t consist only of lowercase English letters.".

Comment: Then it doesn't matter, you can simplify to `\`[^${c}]*${c}\`` just like you can simplify your original regex from `\w` to `.`.